# Image Magic not generating thumbnail for first page of PDF Files

Tags: pdf, image-processing

I have downloaded the Image Magic from the following Link:

http://www.imagemagick.org/download/linux/CentOS/i386/ImageMagick-6.9.1-3.i386.rpm

Extracted the rpm file using `rpm2cpio ImageMagick-6.9.1-3.i386.rpm | cpio -idmv`

Running below command to create the thumbnail for the first page of PDF

```
convert source.pdf[0] output.jpg
```

But I am getting error:

**convert: No match.**

Anyone has any idea why it is not working? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing ImageMagick, you have extracted it instead. What you would want to do is install it.

You could run `yum install ImageMagick` to install it, which will take care of all the necessary dependencies as well. Or, if you wanted to install using the rpm, you should run `rpm -i ImageMagick-6.9.1-3.i386.rpm`. I would suggest going through the `yum` route instead, however.

**Note:** The above answer is based upon the assumption that you are using CentOS or RedHat or a similar distribution. If you are using Ubuntu or a similar distribution, you would need to use `apt-get install imagemagick`.